# Typedef redefinition error when running Unity iOS project in Xcode 9 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I was able to run my Unity 2017.1.0b10 iOS project successfully on my iPhone 6S+ (Using Xcode 9). I changed the `Target SDK` to `Simulator SDK` to try it out on other device simulators then I got the following errors in the `UnityMetalSupport.h` file.

[image]

Below are screenshots of my player settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can someone please assist me

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the reason of the problem, but commenting this rows worked for me